# Get a specific sprite from a group in Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to find a certain sprite in a collision group. In this case, My code checks every platform to see if the player is touching it. If the player is touching the platform, I want the player's bottom y to become the platform's (that the player is touching) top y. I do not know how to grab a certain platform, and edit the attributes of that one. How would I edit my code to make this work?

```
import pygame
import random

WIDTH  = 500
HEIGHT = 400
FPS = 30

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

playerImage = "blockBandit/BlockBandit.png"

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
        self.image = pygame.image.load(playerImage).convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
        self.vx = 0
        self.vy = 0

class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((w, h))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Block Bandit")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

allPlatforms = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
p1 = Platform(0, HEIGHT - 40, WIDTH, 40)
all_sprites.add(p1)
allPlatforms.add(p1)
all_sprites.add(player)


def moveCharacter(object):
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        object.vx += -2
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        object.vx += 2
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        object.vy -= 12
        pygame.quit()

    object.vx = object.vx * 0.9

    if abs(object.vx) < 1:
        object.vx = 0

    if abs(object.vx) > 10:
        if object.vx < 0:
            object.vx = -10
        else:
            object.vx = 10

    object.vy = object.vy + 1
    object.rect.x += object.vx
    object.rect.y += object.vy

    hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(object, allPlatforms, False)
    if hits:
        # object.rect.y = hits[0].rect.midbottom
        object.rect.y -= 1
        object.vy = 0
        if object.rect.bottom < allPlatforms.top:
            object.rect.y = allPlatforms.top
    print(object.rect.midbottom)

running = True

while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    moveCharacter(player)
    # Update State
    all_sprites.update()

    # Render
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)

    # screen.blit(player.icon, (20, 40))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Side note: Don't use built-in names like `object` for your variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hits` is a list of the colliding platform sprites, so you can iterate over it with a `for` loop and set the `object.rect.bottom` to the `platform.rect.top`.

```
hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(object, allPlatforms, False)
for platform in hits:
    object.vy = 0
    object.rect.bottom = platform.rect.top
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I completely forgot about for loops!